# Scroll only the ListView and leave the LinearLayout header on top

Tags: android

I have a design where there is a small portion of the screen dedicated to display the user's profile image. Below, separated by a divider is a list of items contained in a ListView. I want that when I scroll through the list, that the top view of the profile will stay there and not be scrollable, so that only the list is scrollable:

Currently there is a ListView inflated on `onCreate`, then a `header.xml` containing the top image is added like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null));
```

This is the `word_list.xml`:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

This is the header.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_image" />

     <View
        android:id="@+id/headerDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm following a Udacity course so I have no idea what is it. Any short explanation of why it's better to use what you say? Will RecyclerView + Constraint help me achieve what I want? And also, aren't they separated in my code? the ListView isn't part of the header, they are 2 different xml files, or that's not what you meant?

Comment: better use coordinatorlayout with appbarlayout and put the user profile data in appbarlayout and use recyclerrview to render the rest of the list data

Comment: If you don't want expand collapse animation for the header section, no need to use coordinatorlayout. Use a linear layout with orientation VERTICAL. 1st child - include your header.xml, 2nd child - your list view.

Answer (score 0):

your view will look like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingLeft="16dp"
 android:id="@+id/register_container"
 android:paddingRight="16dp"
 android:background="#FFF">

     <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_image"/>
     <View
      android:id="@+id/headerDivider"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" 
      android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

     <ListView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="3"
     android:id="@+id/list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Currently I have 2 xml files: header and word_list, do I need only this View instead of the separated 2? And how do I inflate them in the exisiting code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activity.UnderCoordinatorActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout_cordinate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:background="@color/home">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"

                />

             <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/voter_tv"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#ffff"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="john Doe"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_group"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_layout_cordinate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Currently I have 2 xml files: header and word_list, do I need only this View instead of the separated 2? And how do I inflate them in the exisiting code?

Comment: It depends on, are you going to use the header in another place or is this the only place you want to use your view.

Comment: for inflating your views in one place you could use this: `   <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`